# How is Optional variables a "powerful solution"?

Tags: swift

I was thinking how this "Powerful Solution" according to apple of the Optional Variables is actually powerful if it's something that we already had in Obj-c?

```
var mystring: String? = nil

if mystring {
  //string is not nil
}
```

Second Scenario won't compile

```
var mystring: String = nil

if mystring {
  //string is not nil
}
```

We were able to do this in Obj-C before without any additional set up.

```
NSString * somestring = @"Test";

if(something != [NSNull null]){
  //Do something.
}
```

or

```
NSString * anotherstring = nil;

if(anotherstring == [NSNull null]){
  //display error.
}
```

so I am really confused on how this is that powerful as they claim if it already existed in a former language.

[Some info about Optional Variables](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/understanding-optionals-swift)

Comment: Do you have a specific programming question, or do you just disagree with Apple's choice of words?

Comment: Comparing an object to `[NSNull null]` will nearly always be false, whether it's `nil` or not. (Unless you're parsing JSON with null values, or comparing `if ([NSNull null] == [NSNull null]`, which is also pointless.)

Comment: @0O0O0O0 no, no problem with their words... is a legitimate question because I was wondering how strong Swift is. Which I have liked so far just the lack of Reflection or me not finding the right info which has been hard for me to figure out. E.i get propertiesList and get their names to use for JsonMapping.

Comment: What do you mean by 'strong'? Basically, the issue at hand here is that they believe using Optionals encourages some protection from runtime errors, and to them this is powerful (I agree, but that's obviously up for debate). Swift as a language is a much broader thing to debate about, but I would personally say Optionals help make Swift a better language.

Comment: you are right. No argument there, thanks to the insight of some fellows' answers.

With 'Strong' I mean the optionals and the protection of runtime errors just like you mentioned. I just didn't know that before.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Objective-C a pointer to an object could be `nil`, yes. But there was no enforcement about if `nil` made sense.

```
NSString *shouldNeverBeNil = @"a string!";
shouldNeverBeNil = nil;
NSLog("Hello, %@", shouldNeverBeNil); // "Hello, "
```

In ObjC this compiles fine though we should never say hello to nothing. That's a bug.

But if we do the same in Swift it doesn't even compile and we don't get a runtime bug at all.

```
var shouldNeverBeNil: String = "a string!"
shouldNeverBeNil = nil; // Compilation error.
NSLog("Hello, %@", shouldNeverBeNil); // never happens
```

Optionals allow you to bless variables with the ability to be `nil`. Compilation errors are *always* preferable to runtime errors since it's impossible for an end user of your app to run into a compilation error.

If you want to allow that value to be `nil` Swift makes you bless it explicitly, as an Optional. Now if it's `nil`, you explicitly allowed it and Swift reminds you to handle handle both the `nil` case and the value case in your code.

```
var okToBeNil: String? = "a string!"
okToBeNil = nil;
if okToBeNil != nil {
  NSLog("Hello, %@", okToBeNil!); // never happens
} else {
  NSLog("What is your name?")
}
```

Comment: This will not crash: `[shouldNeverBeNil length]; // Runtime CRASH!`

Comment: Better example: `[someMutableArray addObject:shouldNeverBeNil]`.

Comment: so the powerful part is about the fact that it becomes a Compilation error not a Runtime error and if there is runtime error is because of the Programmers bad decision of giving a variable the blessing of being an Optional. Thanks

Now that makes sense.

Comment: @AlexWayne Sending `nil` to a string formatter won't silently fail. In your example the output is `Hello, (null)`.

Answer (score 4):

The optional is a type on its own (actually an enum), and it can hold 2 values:

- an actual instance/value of the type the optional is used for (corresponding to the `Some` enum case)
- a `nil` value (corresponding to the `None` enum case), which represent the absence of value

The difference with other languages like ObjectiveC is that optionals don't use a valid type value, which can have a meaning in some cases and a different meaning in others.

In objective C, the absence of a reference type is represented by `nil`, which is actually a pointer to the location 0x00000000 (in a 32 bits scenario).

The absence of a value type instead is usually by convention. A function returning an integer can define -1 as absence of value, but -1 is an integer itself, and if the function can return negative values it cannot be used.

In Swift instead an optional can have either a valid integer value, or `None`, which is **not** itself an integer (nor an instance of a class, a struct, or whatever type is used with the optional).

Also, more important, **you cannot assign `nil` to a non optional variable** - that results in a compilation error, hence preventing a lot of common bugs that usually are discovered at runtime, and frequently hard to track down.

Last, whereas in objective C you can use `nil` for reference types, you cannot use for value type (as mentioned above for the integer type). In swift instead an optional can be nil regardless of the contained type - so a `Int?` can be either an integer or `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Swift optionals let you make it **explicit** whether a variable can be `nil`, whereas Objective-C is all for guessing games. Less nightmares about `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors. That's where the power lies.

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate more with a code sample. A few lines of code speak a thousand words.